# Print the specific values from the array

Tags: php, mysql

I get the result from my database i this type of array format.Now i want to print the question,answer and category name from the array what I do?

```
<?php  $v1 = '';
    foreach($var as $data){ 

 ?> 
<div class="faqHeader"> <?php echo $data['category_name'];?> </div>             
    <div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo $data->title;?>">
```

I tried these cod but not get the answer.In $var i get the all the array value

[image]

Comment: you are missing **}** of foreach loop. and what is title ? Try $data['data']['category_name'];

Comment: Probably you should try  $data['data'][0]['category_name']. What's the output of `print_r($data)` in the foreach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to consider:-

1.Your sub-array is again an array so you need to use `foreach()` on sub-array too. (So basically two `foreach()`)

2.You need to close `divs` as well as `foreach()` loops too.

So code need to be like below:-

```
<?php
    foreach($var as $data){ 
        foreach($data['data'] as $dat){
 ?> 
    <div class="faqHeader"> <?php echo $dat['category_name'];?>            
        <div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo $dat['questions'];?>"><?php echo $dat['questions'];?></div>
        <div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo $dat['answer'];?>"><?php echo $dat['answer'];?></div>
    </div> 
<?php } }?>
```

Comment: the one who down-voted please tell the reason. this code is perfectly fine.

Comment: @vinaykapoor  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 1):

you can use two loops to simplify your task:-

```
foreach($var as $index=>data){
    echo $data['name']; // this will be your category name 
    foreach($data as $questionIndex=>$questionData){
        echo $questionData['question'];
        echo $questionData['answer'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your array contains multiple `data` and `data` contains multiple values itself, you need two foreaches here:

```
foreach($var as $item) {
    foreach($item['data'] as $info) {
         var_dump($info);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
<?php  
    $v1 = '';
    foreach($var as $data){ 
?> 
<div class="faqHeader"> <?php echo $data['data'][0]['category_name'];?> </div>             
<div class="panel-group" id="<?php echo $data['name'];?>">
<?php
    }
?>
```

You don't have any 'title' index in your array so you may change it to 'name'